# android material botton with only bottom stroke and shadow

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-button

I want to use material button without top, right and left shadow something like this:
[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: when I use material button has some shadow top and if I use normal button when I use selector state_press to add more shadow like material, shadow add without animation

Comment: I want something like image and when press button add smooth more shadow